# Creating a counter for a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to create a counter to use in a shell (bash) script, each time the script is called 
the number contained has to be increased by one and the number should be kept as six digit number, so the initial value would be 000000, then 000001, then 000002 and so on.....
What i'm doing is, i create a file named 'counter' which contains a 6 digits integer on the first line.
so from the script i have this code:

```
index= cat /path/counter | tail -1   #get the counter
tmp=`expr $index + 1`                #clone and increase the counter
echo "" >/path/counter               #empty the counter
echo ${tmp} >/path/counter           #insert clone
```

The problem is that its not working at the second step, probably is the first step which is actually failing, do you have an advice?

An option would be the following :

```
#!/bin/bash

read index < /path/counter
declare -i tmp=index+1
printf "%06d" $tmp > /path/counter
```

The problem is that it raises the content of the file only until 000007, after that i get:

```
-bash: 000008: value too great for base (error token is "000008")
```

Any Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATE: fixed to include an explicit base marker in the text file, but Glenn Jackman beat me to it.]

You can simplify this a bit:

```
read index < /path/counter   # Read the first line using bash's builtin read
declare -i tmp=index+1       # Set the integer attribute on tmp to simplify the math
printf "10#%06d" $tmp > /path/counter    # No need to explicitly empty the counter; > overwrites
```

Or, you don't even need a temporary variable to hold the incremented value:

```
read index < /path/counter
printf "10#%06d" $(( index+1 )) > /path/counter
```

Comment: Reopened and edited question, the solution you have advised it works only until 000007

Comment: Yuck; the leading zero in the number makes 'read' expect it to be in base-8. I'll try to think of a fix.

Answer (score 3):

You're not reading the index right. Try:

```
index=$(tail -1 /path/counter)
```

Other things to note:

- You don't need the `cat`, `tail` can handle things on its own
- You could replace the backticks with `tmp=$(expr ...)`
- You don't need the `echo ""`, the `>` redirection truncates the file

#### EDIT

To make the number 6 digits wide try `printf` instead of `echo`:

```
printf "%06d", $index
```

Comment: Thnak you! indeed this almost solved it, i only have to find a way on how to make it become a six digit number after increasing it, after increasing the variable by 1 the value 000000 becomes 1, i need it to be 000001, will try some formatter

Comment: Actually i have noticed a small issue after retesting, when i do index=$(tail -f /path/counter) the prompt goes at the next line with a blank line, like if he is waiting for another input, like when you use System.in in Java, and if i want to continue i have to kill the command with Alt+c

Comment: Don't use the `-f` option, it means keep reading forever in case the file should grow.

Answer (score 2):

bash has a mechanism where you can specify a number's base

```
#!/bin/bash
file=/path/to/counter
[[ ! -f "$file" ]] && echo 0 > $file              # create if not exist
index=$(< "$file")                                # read the contents
printf "%06d\n" "$((10#$index + 1))" > "$file"    # increment and write
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work also:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -e /tmp/counter ]
  then
    . /tmp/counter
  fi

if [ -z "${COUNTER}" ]
  then
    COUNTER=1
  else
    COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))
  fi

echo "COUNTER=${COUNTER}" > /tmp/counter

echo ${COUNTER}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
index=$(cat /path/counter| tail -1)
tmp=$(expr $index + 1)
printf "%06d" $tmp > /path/counter
```

Comment: The cat is still useless. `index=$(tail -1 /path/counter)`. See also http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html