# adding a number to a variable

Tags: bash, variables, cat

I am trying to get the contents of a txt file "usernum.txt", get the contents, add one to that number, and replace the current number with the new one.  Here is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/sh
ID=0
cat ''$pwd'usernum.txt' >> $ID
count1=1
IDB=$(($ID+$count1))
rm "usernum.txt"
touch "usernum.txt"
echo $IDB >> usernum.txt
```

It runs but when I open the file, it stays the same.  Any ideas?
Thanks,
Mike

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a counter for a shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317384/creating-a-counter-for-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the output from `cat` into `ID` instead of using `>>`. The way you are doing that you always add to a file named '0'. To store the output of cat use:

```
ID=$( cat 'usernum.txt' )
```

I have also removed the 'pwd' as you do not need it and also it gets escaped by the single quotes.

EDIT: here is a complete working example. Note that if there is no usernum.txt file this will print some errors(cat and rm fail) but still will work(i.e. will print 1 in the file). You should perform a check to see if the file exists to avoid these errors:

```
ID=$( cat 'usernum.txt' )
count1=1
IDB=$(($ID+$count1))
rm "usernum.txt"
touch "usernum.txt"
echo $IDB >> usernum.txt
```